# Sending Email per win32 from python: how to exclude somebody from the email list

Tags: python, win32com

I have a short question. My python program sends automatically emails to the members of some email list. I use the following syntax:

```py
import win32com.client as win32 
outlook = win32.Dispatch('outlook.application')                     
mail = outlook.CreateItem(0)
mail.To="emaillist@bla.bla"
```

Everything works fine but now one member of the list don't want to get Emails anymore. Is there any possibility to simply exclude him from the list? I don't really want to list all of the members of the long list but one manually. :(
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

This has nothing to do with python or win32, the solution it's to remove the person from the mailing list, wherever and however that is managed

Comment: Thank You for the answer. It is not possible to remove the person from the list. The person wants to get all emails which are designated for the list (actually it's simply the list of all members of senior staff) except for this particular one. I also have no chance to create new lists. I am only a python programmer, so I can only change my program, I don't have any other option.

Comment: In that case the recipient needs to make their own filter to discard your messages.